# is there a way to change the attribution model from firebase -> bigquery exported data?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I need to get data from firebase/bigquery. Right now it seems that bigquery installation data is based on "Cross-channel last click" aggregation model. I need the traffic sources that are aggregated under "Google Ads preferred last click" aggregation model.

Comment: Hello, could you help me to better understand if there is something in Bigquery side causing this issue?
Can you be more specific on your issue? What are you trying to achieve? Are you doing an export to bigquery?
Is this [link](https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2018/12/14/how-campaign-attribution-works-google-analytics-firebase/#the-attribution-models) something useful for your use case?

Comment: hey. We're in contact with google themselves and they are familiar with the issue, and there is currently no way to reach this data. They told us that they are working on adding this additional data, but there is no timeline for when the fix will be able.

Comment: Great. Thank you for your feedback! If you would like to collaborate with the community, I'd suggest to edit your Question to further clarify the issue (for instance answering some of the questions that came to my mind) and put the resolution of your issue as an Answer so other members can quickly learn from it. Thanks anyway.